# Wait for Netbeans Platform application to deserialize all previously opened windows

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, rcp

I am developing a Netbeans Platform application and face the following problem:
When closing my app persists the opened windows A and B.
Upon reopening my app the windows get deserialized one by one. First A then B.
It is very possible that I receive new information for window B during the reopening of window A.
At this point the program logic decides whether to open a new window B or use the existing one. But since window B doesn't exist yet it opens a new window. Afterwards the "old" window B is opened via deserialization.

Is there a way to wait until all windows are opened? I could delay the opening of additional windows until all windows are opened.

I found nothing in the [Windows-System API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/doc-files/api.html) or in the class WindowManager.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

13 Views and 0 answers, we need more netbeans platform developers!

```
    WindowManager.getDefault().addWindowSystemListener(new WindowSystemListener() {

        @Override
        public void beforeLoad(WindowSystemEvent wse) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterLoad(WindowSystemEvent wse) {
            // at this point all windows are opened
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeSave(WindowSystemEvent wse) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterSave(WindowSystemEvent wse) {
        }
    });
```